# Angular 5 ng-select

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I am using ng-select component from https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select
. However the content of the dropdown is in some cases too long. The string in the dropdown will be shortened with ... Is it possible to make the dropdown bigger than the input width, according to the length of the content? Possibly with CSS styling (custom).

```
<div layout="row">
    <label>Your first ng-select</label>
    <ng-select class="custom" [items]="cities"
               bindLabel="name"
               placeholder="Select city"
               [(ngModel)]="selectedCity">
    </ng-select>

    <label>Your first ng-select</label>
    <ng-select class="custom" [items]="cities"
               bindLabel="name"
               placeholder="Select city"
               [(ngModel)]="selectedCity">
    </ng-select>
</div
```

Answer (score 3):

In the CSS/SCSS (what you are using for styling) set

```
.ng-dropdown-panel {
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

However it doesn't look that good...

[image]

Alternative:

Remove `white-space: nowrap;` from `.ng-dropdown-panel .ng-dropdown-panel-items .ng-option` then it breaks into multiple lines.

[image]

Comment: Tried to change the style, but it doesn't work for me. Changed the demo of the github page a little bit. Can you see how to do change it here? 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-2u7ces

Comment: @J.D To change the `white-space` style: `ng-select .ng-dropdown-panel .ng-dropdown-panel-items .ng-option {
  white-space: normal;
}
`

Answer (score 0):

1. Add encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None.
2. Give it a class name. And override the CSS using it

```js
.ng-select.custom .ng-value-container
    {
      height: 10px;
    }
```

Here ng-select is the component and  custom is the class name.